# Can't get data from a computed property with ember-model

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I am making an app with `ember.js` and `ember-model`

I have a model named `Plugin` defined as follows:

```
Eme.Plugin = Ember.Model.extend
  id: Ember.attr()
  name: Ember.attr()
  description: Ember.attr()
  downloads: Ember.attr()
  tags: Ember.attr()

Eme.Plugin.url = "/api/v1/plugins"
Eme.Plugin.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create()
Eme.Plugin.collectionKey = 'plugins'
```

I want show the most downloaded in `index.hbs` ( i use `ember-rails`)

And i fetch data in `IndexRoute` 's `setupController` hook:

```
Eme.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    console.log Eme.Plugin.findAll().toArray()
    controller.set 'plugins', Eme.Plugin.findAll()
```

Output :

```
[nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function, getEach: function…]
```

But in chrome console i execute `Eme.Plugin.findAll().toArray()`, i got the results as follows:

```
[{
  __ember1377710636537: "ember404"
  __ember1377710636537_meta: Meta
  _dirtyAttributes: Array[0]
  _reference: Object
  _super: undefined
  get _data: function() {}
  isLoaded: true
  isNew: false
  set _data: function(value) {}
  __proto__: Object
}, {
  ...
}, {
  ...
}]
```

In my `IndexController` have a computed property:

```
Eme.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend

  mostDownloads:(->
    # console.log @get('plugins').slice(0, 3)
    @get('plugins').slice(0, 3)
  ).property('plugins')
```

and i iterate the `mostDownloads` but there is nothing to show, however when i output `{{plugins.length}}`, i can't get the count of all my data

Who can give a hand to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins looks like an array and would need to use the .@each iterator like so:

```
Eme.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    // Code
}).property('plugins.@each')
```

Here is documentation on @each http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Regarding your array length, I've never had much luck using .length, for length I usually do

```
plugins.get('length')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt, now my `indexController` like this and it work well

    `Eme.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend

      mostDownloads:(->
        @get('plugins').slice(0, 3)
      ).property('plugins.@each')`

Answer (score 0):

I propose two changes to make you app working.

### First

I assume since it's called `plugins` *(plural)* the call to `.findAll()` returns an array of `plugins` for this to work you should change your controller type to be an `ArrayController`. Then because you are using `@` aka. `this` in your computed property you should use the fat arrow `=>` to have the right reference to `this`, so the resulting `IndexController` should look like:

```
Eme.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend

  mostDownloads:(=>
    # console.log @get('content').slice(0, 3)
    @get('content').slice(0, 3)
  ).property('content.[]')
```

Notice also that we observe `content.[]` this will trigger whenever the content array changes, items added or removed etc. you could also use `content.@each` but this is better suited for when you need to observe changes to the properties of a `plugin` record in the array, e.g. `content.@each.name`.

### Second

Now change also how you set the `plugins` collection on your controller, you should rather set the controller's `content` property since this is what it is for:

```
Eme.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    # console.log Eme.Plugin.findAll().toArray()
    controller.set 'content', Eme.Plugin.findAll()
```

This line `console.log Eme.Plugin.findAll().toArray()` will not work the way you expect because when you call it it will give you a promise back and not the array that is still underway (async...).

And a last change, to print out the plugins length, use the `afterModel` hook of your `IndexRoute`, since this is the right time when the `model` promise has being resolved (the async operation has given back control to your app).

```
Eme.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
  ...
  afterModel: (plugins, transition) ->
    console.log plugins.get 'length'
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not want to put `plugins` into `content`, since now `IndexRoute`, I have additional data to show, such as Tags, News, etc.